# How to create UIScrollView using universal story board?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode6, universal-storyboard

How to create simple UIScrollView app using Universal Storybioard in XCode 6?

In my case All content view element is designed inside storyboard (ex: form view that have many input that you need scroll the screen)

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You would just make it as if it were for a non-universal app. Use auto-layout to make sure it runs nicely on all devices and maybe make use of the new size classes to have one look for iPhone, but another for iPad.

Comment: Thats the problem, i don't quite understand how the new universal storyboard mode work, using XCode 5, i can create Storyboard Designed UIScrollView app with autolayout, but same technique seems doesn't work in XCode6, the element i design didn't appear on debug mode even when it is did appear in Preview

Comment: Would a link to a tutorial on size classes help? I used this youtube video to learn how to use them. Might be worth a look. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng